# Integrating an integrand with Fourier series as denominator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

It is out of curiosity. It is possible to integrate the following integral without any numerical method:

> $$\int {1 \over \sum_{k=1}^N c_ke^{i\pi x k}} dx, \quad x\in [-\pi, \pi]$$

If it is not so, can we use any numerical method?

Comment: Your tag is definite-integral, do you mean $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$.?

Comment: You can easily rewrite this into a complex integral of a rational function along a circle. However in order to solve this, you would need to know the roots of the denominator, which in general is not possible, if $N$ gets to large.

Comment: mistakes !! thank you for your suggestions.